# Tried to update Emacs on my mac using Homebrew, and now it doesn't run at all

Tags: install, upgrade, mac

Up until an hour ago I had a working installation of Emacs version 26.2 on my Late 2013 iMac running macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 (this is the latest version available for my computer). I would run Emacs from the terminal by `cd`-ing to a certain directory and then executing:

> emacs

Everything was dandy until, yesterday, for no good reason, I decided it was time to update my Emacs to the latest version. This was especially asinine since I'm in the middle of writing my thesis and I'm already behind schedule. But I went along and tried to update it via Homebrew.

I described my failed attempt to update Emacs in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418256/homebrew-says-i-got-the-latest-version-of-emacs-installed-but-the-emacs-command?noredirect=1#comment586676_418256) post that I posted yesterday to the apple stachexchange forum.

A certain user named nohillside suggested in the comments that I uninstall emacs, remove Emacs from the Applications directory, and then try to reinstall it. I followed this suggestion about an hour ago. Unfortunately, it didn't succeed in updating my Emacs installation. Worst: the command `emacs` no longer works at all.

Please help me get Emacs working again.

Comment: In your other question you show that `emacs --version` works, so it's not true that "the command emacs no longer works at all"?  Or did you subsequently uninstall the working version?

Comment: In any case, I think OSX users tend to use https://emacsforosx.com/ ?  I'm not sure, but maybe try that if nothing else is working.

Comment: @phils: I followed a suggestion made in the comments and uninstalled emacs and subsequently reinstalled it. It's all described in the other post.

Comment: If you still have the version 27.2 installed, to start it from terminal type ```emacs-27.2 -Q``` and if this works, then you may try without ```-Q``` or just start bisecting your init file. I had the same problem when moving from 26.3 to 27.1, and solved by bisecting and removing a package.

Comment: @Ian: `emacs-27.2 -Q` doesn't work: `zsh: command not found: emacs-27.2`

Comment: But the ```emacs``` folder can be found in ```/usr/local/Cellar/emacs```? See also this: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation - you are at "best-effort basis". If nothing works, then emacsforosx.com.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, an `emacs` folder exists under `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs`.

Comment: And further there is an Emacs.app there? and inside the folder ```bin``` should be emacsclient and emacs commands.

Comment: Try to uninstall what you have now and replace with this: https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus - it is better for org-mode.

Comment: @Ian: Where is the Emacs.app supposed to be? Under `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/27.2/bin` there are `emacsclient` and `emacs` but `emacs` is not an executable, only `emacsclient` is. `emacs` is an alias.

Comment: In ```/usr/local/cellar/emacs/27.2/``` should be Emacs.app; so try to reinstall (or install emacs-plus)

Comment: @Ian: Do you know why the Emacs Plus page you linked to says: "Emacs 27 failing" (see [this](https://imgur.com/bURRpBi) screenshot)?

Comment: I have no idea, I just reinstalled emacs-plus@27 two days ago, after checking mitsuharu's emacs-mac (which I do not like it).

Comment: @Ian: At any rate, I've followed your suggestion and installed Emacs Plus and it works. So thanks!